# error: cannot find symbol method readLines(File,Charset)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on a project and I updated the gradle dependencies so I could get FileUtil. The last line in my build (Module:app) is what I updated (implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'). I've used this in the past and it worked, but now I'm getting errors for both readLines and writeLines. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
```

}

```
// this function will load items by reading every line of the data file
private void loadItems() {
    try {
        items = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(getDataFile(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
    } catch (IOExcpetion e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error reading items", e);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

// This function saves items by writing them into the data file
private void saveItem() {
    try {
        FileUtils.writeLines(getDataFile(), item);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error writing items", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what FileUtils class are you using?

Comment: @Stultuske I'm using import android.os.FileUtils;

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUtils I don't see a readLines method in there.

Comment: @Stultuske changed the import to import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; it works now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add this import statement

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

This will work.

Comment: Always give answers with some explanation.